# How to use estimate in forestplot package?

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I'm trying to use the `forestplot` package to include estimate (beta) values. I can do it just fine if I were to use means instead of estimates using the code below:

```
library(forestplot)
library(dplyr)

tabletext <- cbind(c("", "Group", "A", "At 1M", "At 3M", "At 6M", "B", "A1 1M", "At 3M", "At 6M", "C", "At 1M", "At 3M", "At 6M"),
               c("Mean", "", "", "0.11", "0.11", "0.0062", "", "0.17", "0.24", "0.22", "", "0.081", "0.11", "0.014"),
               c("Lower CI", "", "", "0.22", "0.28", "0.48", "", "0.16", "0.17", "0.26", "", "0.26", "0.27", "0.51"),
               c("Upper CI", "", "", "0.45", "0.51", "0.49", "", "0.52", "0.64", "0.71", "", "0.43", "0.69", "0.48"))
fp <- structure(list(mean  = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.11, 0.11, 0.0062, NA, 0.17, 0.24, 0.22, NA, 0.081, 0.11, 0.014), 
                                  lower = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.22, 0.28, 0.48, NA, 0.16, 0.17, 0.26, NA, 0.26, 0.27, 0.51),
                                  upper = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.45, 0.51, 0.49, NA, 0.52, 0.64, 0.71, NA, 0.43, 0.69, 0.48)),
                             .Names = c("mean", "lower", "upper"), 
                             row.names = c(NA, -14L),
                             class = "data.frame")
fp2<-fp %>% 
  forestplot(labeltext = tabletext, 
         clip = c(0.005, 1), 
         xlog = TRUE, 
         col = fpColors(box = "royalblue",
                        line = "darkblue"))
```

However, I'm not quite sure how to modify the code to use estimates instead. The code above doesn't work for estimates because some of my values are negative. I'm trying to get an outcome similar to the figure I have attached. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your data. Most of your mean values don't fall between the upper and lower confidence bounds, which can't be right. Also, you say you have some negative values, but there aren't any negative values in the data frames you provided. If the values in your data frame represent proportions, then you could convert them to log odds to get the beta values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I agree with the comment above, mean values lying out of data range are inexplicable. Perhaps it's not mean but some other measure?</s>
(Sorry about that. These values depict CI. The estimate can certainly be out of confidence interval.My fault.)

Anyway, I can spot  the reason why these values  are not showing on the plot. The `xlog` parameter is converting  xtics to logarithmic values( which are -ve for the decimal values) and the  `clip` parameter is clipping out anything less than 0.005

Switching off Xlog will mark the values in the plot :

```
fp %>% 
  forestplot(labeltext = tabletext, 
             clip = c(0, 1), 
             xlog = F, 
             col = fpColors(box = "royalblue",
                            line = "darkblue"))
```

**Edit Note:** I've edited  code to borrow proper labels from tabletext